Link two tables across two sheets with the same column
In one sheet I have the following data:



ID
DOB
Address




2343234
20/1/1990



3454324
11/12/1986




In another sheet I have more columns with the same key column ID



ID
Score 1
Score 2




2343234
67
33


3454324
32
21



I would like to link the two tables with the Column ID, so if a new ID is entered in the first table it appears in the second table and if I order the first table it reorders the second table.
Can you kindly advise please

I can't see a way (short of VBA) that the 2nd table should be sorted (with all its columns) based on the other table being sorted.

Agreed, without VBA you'll need a third (reporting/pivot) table that will take into account sorting of the first table AND linkage of id's to scores of the second table
